# Error when calling ios NativeModule from react-native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I'm developing a react native application on a M1 Pro Macbook, and I'm having this error when calling a NativeModule.

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The NativeModule method that I'm calling is like a "middleware" to make request to backend services that don't accept requests coming directly from JS.

This is my NativeModule Swift file:

```
import Foundation

@objc(Request)
class Request: NSObject {
  
  @objc
  func makeRequest(_ requestUrl: String, requestQuery: String, token: String, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,  reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    let url = URL(string: requestUrl+requestQuery)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    if(!token.isEmpty) {
      request.setValue("Bearer "+token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
      if let data = data {
        resolve(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) )
      } else if let error = error {
        reject("500", "error", error)
      }
    }
    task.resume()
  }
  
  @objc static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
      return true
  }
  
}
```

The Obj-C file to expose it to the bridge:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Request, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(makeRequest: (NSString)requestUrl requestQuery: (NSString)requestQuery token: (NSString)token resolve:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve reject:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)

@end
```

And that's my call to the NativeModule on React Native side:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
import {INSTANCE_URL} from '../config/salesforce';
import {STORAGE_ITEMS} from '../constants/async-storage.constants';

export const executeQuery = async (query: string): Promise<any> => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_ITEMS.TOKEN);

  if (!token) {
    //throw unauthorized and go back to login page
  }

  const response = await NativeModules.Request.makeRequest(
    `${INSTANCE_URL}/services/data/v54.0/query/?q=`,
    query,
    token,
  );
  return JSON.parse(response);
};
```

This same NativeModule call is working on Android, so it seems to be a problem with the communication between React < - > iOS, or on the params definition.

Can you guys help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution for the ones that may be having the same problem.

That's the reason: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest#1776617

Authorization is a Reserved HTTP Header, so I had to set him through the URLSessionConfiguration, like that:

```
let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
sessionConfiguration.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
    "Authorization": token
]
let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
```

This solved the problem for me. My final code for the swift file looks like that:

```
import Foundation

@objc(Request)
class Request: NSObject {
  
  @objc
  func makeRequest(_ requestUrl: String, requestQuery: String, token: String, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,  reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    let stringUrl: String = requestUrl + requestQuery
    let url = URL(string: stringUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    sessionConfiguration.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
        "Authorization": token
    ]
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
      if let data = data {
        resolve(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) )
      } else if let error = error {
        reject("500", "error", error)
      }
    }
    task.resume()
  }
  
  @objc static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
      return true
  }
  
}
```